# How to implement advertisements in an iphone application?

Tags: iphone, integration, ads

We are developing an application for iphone that requires advertisement to be shown up on the screen.  We are totally new to this concept.  Could anyone assist us with this.  Any sample will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Zach.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you create an account with a company that provides you with 2 things:

- an API key
- an iPhone SDK

You download the SDK and add the required files (header, libraries) to your iPhone project.  To integrate the ad SDK, you set your API key in a few simple calls, and register a delegate that lets you know when interesting things happen (e.g. "a new ad was downloaded").  The SDK generally lets one specify the location of the ad-view or allows the developer to provide a view to use.

I have used AdWhirl for about 6 months.  AdWhirl is a neat idea in that they will fetch ads from multiple sources based on availability (not all companies have infinite ads to give you) and even by how well the source is performing (how much $$$ you are making).

AdWhirl lets you run custom ads as well.  Want to advertise your other apps every so often?

AdWhirl was acquired by AdMob recently AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks Brian for your taking your time out and answering.  I have successfully implemented it. But, the would like the target platform to be Iphone OS 3.0 and simulator to be 3.0 instead of 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Go Check out Admob.  They are the most used ad network and are easy to setup.  They provide clear, concise instructions on how to set it up and you should see ads in less than 10 minutes.

Comment: I thank you also ConeyBeare. I really helped me to startup with.